# How to decode JSON values without key?

Tags: php, json

i have json

```
{"http://www.google.com/","http://www.facebook.com/","http://www.wordpress.com/",0}
```

How can i print like

```
 http://www.google.com/
 http://www.facebook.com/
 http://www.wordpress.com/
```

Comment: google json_decode function

Comment: That example is not valid JSON.

Comment: i need url only for my project,then how can i make json properly

Comment: Take a trip over to http://json.org such that JSON can be correctly identified/created in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use this function

```
function getUrls($string) {
        $regex = '/https?\:\/\/[^\" ]+/i';
        preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches);
        //return (array_reverse($matches[0]));
        return ($matches[0]);
}
```

like this

```
$json_str = '{"http://www.google.com/","http://www.facebook.com/","http://www.wordpress.com/",0}';
$arr = getUrls($json_str);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($arr);
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
Array
(
    [0] => http://www.google.com/
    [1] => http://www.facebook.com/
    [2] => http://www.wordpress.com/
)
```

Answer (score 3):

The lame answer :)

```
$json = '{"http://www.google.com/","http://www.facebook.com/","http://www.wordpress.com/",0}';
$json = str_replace(array('{', '}'), array('[',']'), $json);
print_r(json_decode($json));
```

Answer (score 3):

Start with *real* [JSON](http://json.org), representing an array of values.

```
$json = '["http://www.google.com/","http://www.facebook.com/",".."]';
```

Then use [`json_decode`](http://php.net/json_decode).

```
$arr = json_decode($json);
print_r($arr);
```

Answer (score 2):

look at this sample code in php

```
  <?php
   $jsonData = '{ "user":"John", "age":22, "country":"United States" }';
   $phpArray = json_decode($jsonData);
   print_r($phpArray);
   foreach ($phpArray as $key => $value) { 
   echo "<p>$key | $value</p>";
   }
  ?>
```

Comment: While this example works, it doesn't work for the OP because he/she doesn't actually have JSON ..